# Getting "class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]" error even though main signature is correct

Tags: java

My DrJava was working fine, but now I keep getting the folowing error whenever I run anything:

```
Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[].
```

So it will compile OK, but then it shoots out the error . This happens even though everything I test does indeed have a public static void main(String[] args) in it. It seems like a classpath/resources type of error.  I appreciate any tips

EDIT: my class

```
public class Test{


public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println(" hashmap ");

}

}
```

Comment: Can't help until you show us the actual code, and how you are running it.

Comment: I know this seems too obvious but... did you save it?

Comment: Also, how you are running it? Is your source file named as `Test.java`?

Comment: @RohitJain - yes it is

Comment: @RohitJain - I'm using the drJava program, clicking "Compile" then "Run"

Comment: Try creating a whole new class, call it `Test2`. Does the problem persist?

Comment: @Adel. I'm pretty sure, you are running the wrong file. Make sure you run the file containing the `main` method. There can't be any other issue. Try *right-clicking* on the file, and *Run* from there.

Comment: @acdcjunior- Yeah it does. I think the issue is with DrJava - OK i'll try re-downloading it and see if that helps

Comment: @RohitJain - OK understood, I'll do that. thanks!

Comment: Most likely, you are not running the version you think you are.  Is there any reason not to use one of the main IDEs, Eclipse, Netbeans or IntellIJ

Comment: You only need the one routine, in the class that is named on the `java` command.  First switch to the directory where Test.java is and erase Test.class ( *Note I said erase Test.class, not Test.java* ), then do `javac Test.java`.  Verify that a new Test.class got created.  Finally do `java Test`.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - OK so the main reason is convenience, as DrJava opens up very quickly(eclipse is rather slow to boot-up). however, yes I can just keep Eclipse open most of the time. Will look into intellJ also. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to reinstall java, nor is it a java version issue. It may be the way that your are running the program.
To check if it is a problem with your code, do the following:

Make a new folder and put Test.java in it.

Open up **Command Line** Or **Terminal** and change to that folder .

Type **javac Test.java**. Test.class should be in the folder now.

If you want, open up the class with a text editor. This is what I get:

```
˛∫æ2

<init>()VCodeLineNumberTablemain([Ljava/lang/String;)V
SourceFile      Test.java        hashmap                  Testjava/lang/Objectjava/lang/SystemoutLjava/io/PrintStream;java/io/PrintStreamprintln(Ljava/l    ang/String;)V!  *∑±
    %   ≤∂±
```

Back to the command line or terminal, type **java Test**.

If you get an error, which you shouldn't, I don't know what to say. It should produce the string " hashmap " on to the command line or terminal.

Why re-installing Dr. Java may not work is because you may be using the same working directory, causing same run settings to be used. Dr. Java may be running an external program, one without a main method.

I think that you should install the [Eclipse IDE](http://eclipse.com) for Java. It is much easier to get around, it looks nicer, and it runs the file or project that you are looking at currently.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For some odd reason, when I create a new folder and make a HelloWorld program there, it works Ok. could it be some odd access-specifier issue?

Comment: It could be. It would explain why the program says that there is no main method: it is not visible to the compiler. For a mac, I would say that the permissions were switched around somehow in the [.DS_Store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store)

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing wrong with the *code*, so the problem must be with the *environment*.

- Check that you're *actually* executing *that* class. Find out where the class that's executed is specified and check it's correct
- Check that you're *compiling* the class. Maybe the code you're looking at has not been compiled and you're trying to execute an old version that was compild *before* you coded a `main()`
- Check your classpath. Is the compiled class accessible in the classpath of the java command

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this problem happens because may be mistake in saving file.you always your file using double quotes and with the .java extension which is main class means that class containing main method.

you should save your file by class name which is public .if there is two classes and both have main method then you should save  your file by class name that is public and that class will be run.As like your compiler looking for main method in public static void main(String [] args) that is contract for jvm to run a programme
so it is not able to found that main method that is static and it looking for your Dr class.java
See this Example it have two main methods and practice these kinds of question.I also got this kind of problem in starting.

```
public class TestFirst
{
 public static void main(String   [] args){

System.out.println(" TestFirst ");
```

}

}

```
class Test{

public static void main(String   [] args){

System.out.println(" hashmap ");
```

}

}

if you save pro-gramme by "TestFirst.java" then o/p will come TestFirst if you do some mistake in main method because we have saved our programme by TestFirst then you will get error like you got.

@ 2nd mistake may be this

```
debian@debian:~/Geany_java$ javac Test1.java
debian@debian:~/Geany_java$ java Test1
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
at Test1.main(Test1.java:11)
```

your classpath has not set properly See above Compiling successfully but running showing same kind of error you got.Which OS is using I can guide you properly.

Answer (score 1):

Check that actually your file have the .java termination nor the .dj

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code.

It is the executing environment which might have problem. Please share the details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For some odd reason, when I create a new folder and make a HelloWorld program there, it works Ok. could it be some odd access-specifier issue?

Answer (score 1):

- Check if program compiled correctly.
- Check time-stamo of .class file.
- Check permissions on folder/directory where class-files are getting generated.
- Check if DrJAVA has appropriate permission on the directory.
- Did you create a file, compiled it with out main?
- Check class-path. Might be possible that previous class file is still being found by JDK in classpath.
- Try compiling .java file from cmdLine instead of editor.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, your code is fine.  There must be a problem with your environment.  I recently experienced a similar issue when [investigating and answering this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956914/is-every-class-an-instance-of-class/17957666?noredirect=1#comment26247265_17957666).

Basically, in that question, the code `Void.class instanceof Class` resulted in a compiler error because a user-made `Class.class` existed in the classpath, so one `Class` (the Java built-in `java.lang.Class`) didn't match with the given `Class` (user-made).

Something similar may be at work here.  It is possible that there is a user-made `String.class` in your classpath.  Then in your `main` signature, `String[] args` would mean an array of *your* `String`, when Dr. Java must be looking for a `main` method taking an array of the Java built-in `String`, i.e. `java.lang.String[]`.  If you have a custom `String` class in your classpath (or in your project?), then the Java compiler will choose it over the built-in `String`.  If you were to compile and run your `Test` class from the command line, then you would get the runtime error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main`.

Following @S0urceC0ded's suggestion, you may find this when looking at `Test.class` in a text editor:

```
main([LString;)V  // A user-made String class
```

instead of what it's supposed to be:

```
main([Ljava/lang/String;)V  // The built-in java.lang.String class
```

If so, remove your own `String` class (at least the .class file, but also the .java file so the .class file isn't re-created) from the classpath, and compile and run your `Test` class again.

Without a look at your environment, I can't tell for sure that this is the issue.  But it can explain it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dr.Java as IDE, then you need to make sure that the main class containing 'public static void main' should be at the very top of your program. Otherwise Dr.Java throws this error during runtime.