# Is every class an instance of Class

Tags: java

The code below won't compile, why?

```
System.out.println(Void.class instanceof Class);
```

This won't compile either

```
//according to oracle doc, the type of Void.TYPE is Class<Void>
System.out.println(Void.TYPE instanceof Class);
```

The error message is

```
VoidTest.java:6: inconvertible types found : java.lang.Class<java.lang.Void> required: Class System.out.println(Void.TYPE instanceof Class);
```

And i am using Darwin Kernel Version 12.4.0 and Java version "1.6.0_51"

They won't compile using emacs + java + javac

They compile fine using online repl:http://www.javarepl.com/console.html or use eclipse on my machine

Comment: Those both compile just fine for me...

Comment: Compiles for me, too. Show an `SSCCE` that doesn't compile.

Comment: Compiles for me too and probably everyone else too.

Comment: This code should compile, but it might not produce the results you are expecting.  Are you expecting a particular boolean output, and seeing the opposite?

Comment: They both compile, and I get "true" for both after running.

Comment: I've tried this on Eclipse using JDK 1.6.0_30 and didn't compile.

Comment: Could someone for whom it does not compile please post the error message(s) and an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)?

Comment: VoidTest.java:6: inconvertible types
found   : java.lang.Class<java.lang.Void>
required: Class
 System.out.println(Void.TYPE instanceof Class);
                        ^
1 error

Comment: Compiles and runs on Windows 7: 32-bit JDK 1.5.0_22, 64-bit JDK 1.6.0_45, and 64-bit JDK 1.7.0_25.  **But**, I reproduced @charles_ma's error on Unix Solaris 10 JDK 1.5.0_30.

Comment: @rgettman yup I got the error on my mac~ also unix

Comment: I can add `System.out.println(Integer.class instanceof Class);` and `System.out.println(Integer.TYPE instanceof Class);`, and I get the same results as for `Void`: compiler errors on `Integer.TYPE` and on `Integer.class` if `Void.class` and `Void.TYPE` have compiler errors, and no errors on `Integer.TYPE` and on `Integer.class` if `Void.class` and `Void.TYPE` have no compiler errors.

Comment: Compiles fine on Ubuntu 12.04, OpenJDK 7, eclipse juno.

Comment: The fact that some people can compile and run the code is not a motive nor to downvote nor to vote to close the question. OP's trying to understand **why** this can't compile in his/her environment (on the basis that **it should**), what could be the reason and simple saying *I can compile this* doesn't help. Note that this doesn't compile on my current environment (as posted in a previous comment before).

Comment: I've edited the test program in my answer to add the corresponding casts. I would be interested in what happens to the casts with a compiler that rejects the instanceof tests.

Comment: I guess it is a problem on the IDE (in my case, Eclipse Juno) because I made another test creating a java file in another directory an editing it with notepad, then compiling and executing using `javac` and `java` respectively and the output was `true true` (separated by a line break).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza actually i didn't use any IDE on my machine, just emacs + javac + java

Comment: Do you happen to have a custom `Class.class` file somewhere on your classpath?  Probably from a previous test file from a past StackOverflow question, I found and removed `Class.class` from my directory and then it compiled and ran fine.

Comment: @rgettman that was my problem, I looked for a `Class` class that I've created and changed its name, now everything compiles with no problem. That must be an answer.

Comment: @rgettman you are right, i had a Class class on my path too~ thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer...

I was able to duplicate the compiler error until I noticed I had a `Class.class` file in my directory (probably from attempting to analyze a past StackOverflow question).

I deleted that file, and then it compiled and ran just fine.

```
$ javac Main.java
Main.java:7: inconvertible types
found   : java.lang.Class<java.lang.Void>
required: Class
        System.out.println(Void.class instanceof Class);
                               ^
Main.java:8: inconvertible types
found   : java.lang.Class<java.lang.Void>
required: Class
        System.out.println(Void.TYPE instanceof Class);
                               ^
2 errors
$ rm Class.class
$ javac Main.java
$ java Main
true
true
```

Some custom `Class` class had taken precedence over the built-in `java.lang.Class`.

Comment: Or use java.lang.Class instead of Class rather than delete Class.class.

Comment: Sure, that would work, but it's error prone when you use `Class` again.  And it took this community 45 minutes to track down the error this time.  It's generally a bad idea to name your own class the same name as something built-in to Java, especially in `java.lang` which doesn't need to be `import`ed.

Comment: +1 Nice detective work. I suppose `required: Class` instead of `required: java.lang.Class` was the sole clue.

Comment: I've voted to reopen because of the value of this answer, and its generalization. If you see weird behavior related to a standard class, such as Class, check for a local declaration.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a comment, not an answer, but I need to show some code. Here is my test program:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String arg[])
  {
    System.out.println(Void.class instanceof Class);
    System.out.println(Void.TYPE instanceof Class);
    Class c1 = (Class)Void.class;
    Class c2 = (Class)Void.TYPE;
    System.out.println(c1.getName());
    System.out.println(c2.getName());
  }
}
```

I've compiled and run it under Eclipse with both compliance level 1.7 and compliance level 1.3. Both ways, it compiles and prints:

```
true
true
java.lang.Void
void
```

The reason for adding the casts is that one legitimate reason for the compiler to reject an instanceof comparison is if the corresponding cast would be a compile time error. I do get warnings on the casts, but not errors.

Comment: I've just copied/pastes this in my IDE and shows *Cannot cast from Class<Void> to Class*.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That is probably the underlying problem. Rejection of the instanceof test follows from rejection of the cast. Could this be a case of a compiler option being set to be more stringent than the standard requires?

Comment: After reading the last comment of @rgettman, I looked for a `class Class` in my project and found that this was the culprit of my compile error on my Java project. Just changed the name of this silly `Class`, recompiled and worked with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Void.class is an instance of Class(notice capitalization).

An `object` is the instance of a class.

And both of them compiles just fine

Comment: But a class is an instance of Class (Class != class). An Object is an instance of a class. A class is an instance of Class.

Comment: Pardon me: classes are not instances of something. They are an programming concept. Objects are instances of some class. Each object in Java has an associated Class object describing its class.

Comment: @GyroGearless:  Pardon me: a class most certainly *is* an instance.  Classes *in general* is a programming concept, but each class is an application of that concept -- and, particularly in Java, that application yields concrete results (`.class` files and `Class` objects).  But either way, the JVM is not a programmer, and doesn't give a hoot about semantic games or abstract concepts.  To it, a `Class` object *is* a class -- and if something can't provide the object, then the class simply doesn't exist.